# Where to post/upload the new theme for WordPress theme repository

Tags: theme-development, themes, wordpress.org

After a long dedication, I developed a GPL Theme for WordPress. I want it to be available for FREE to WordPress.org Theme Repository. But consulting many Codex resources, I found no direct link where I can post/upload my theme for the WP Theme Repository.

**Q: Where can I upload my theme for WP Theme Repository?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yap, it's actually a bit tricky, because there's NO direct link saying "Upload" in WordPress.org. But there is a way:

You have to have a WordPress.org account first. After login with the account, look at the left panel, where resides a link saying: **"Theme Authors"** under "Themes" main menu. Click on it, and it'll direct you to the theme upload page:
http://wordpress.org/themes/upload/

[image: Theme Upload Page]

Choose your theme and then press the <kbd>**Upload**</kbd> button. It'll create a new trac record for your theme, and afterward a theme reviewer will be assigned to your theme. Assignment of a theme may take time (even a month) due to the traffic of themes. And after assigning, Reviewing a theme can also take time - so your patient is required.

> **NOTE:** Mozilla Firefox sometimes creates problem uploading theme. In that case, use Google Chrome or Apple's Safari instead. **And** before Uploading your theme (`theme-name.zip`), ensure that there is NO `thumbs.db` file exists in any of your theme folders.

**THEME UPDATE**
If your theme has a new update, just go to the same page, and choose the `.zip` file and press the <kbd>**Upload**</kbd> button. It'll automatically assign your new version of the theme to another trac record. And rest of the process is similar to the first time.